# CRSError while reading geojson file using geopandas in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

While reading a `geojson` file using `GeoPandas` in jupyter notebook, I'm getting following error.

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(filepath)
```

Error:

CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)

I also got the warning while importing `geopandas`:

Warning:

PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name

What does it mean?. I have been using 'geopandas' for a long time. Never saw these error and warning.

Comment: It seems to be a corrupted installation of `pyproj`. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: @martinfleis It was working fine until then. Why now? However, I have already updated geopandas to latest version. anyways, I consider your suggestion.

Comment: @martinfleis reinstalling `pyproj` didn't help.

Comment: According to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/990), it looks like someone else had this problem and changing the pyproj version solved it. Maybe you did an environment update that caused the issue to suddenly appear? Try `conda list pyproj` in the Anaconda command prompt to see what version you have installed.